# Spring boot application with 2 database one application db with hibernate and other external db just for querying using jdbc

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

Hi have create the Spring boot application and this app has 2 databases one is the application DB and I want the Hibernate to take care of this schema creation and update and there is other database on some other server to which i just wants to connect with and do some crud operation. I have this config:

```
#--------------------- DB Connection for app db ------------------
server.port = 8080
spring.datasource.platform= postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=test
```

```
#--------------------External Database Configuration-----------------
invitro.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://abc.xyz.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/test_db
ext.datasource.username=postgres
ext.datasource.password=test
ext.datasource.jpa.show-sql=true
ext.datasource.jpa.generate-ddl=false
ext.datasource.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
ext.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Following is the way i am creating the bean for external DB

```
@Configuration
public class ExternalDbConfig {

    // @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ext.datasource")
    @Bean(name = "extDataSource")
    public DataSource specDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

But when i build application i get the error like this

```
GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table bmv_load_status (id  serial not null, bmv_id int4, datetime_created timestamp, datetime_updated timestamp, data_loaded_flg boolean, no_result_flg boolean, to_update_flg boolean, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
```

I don't know if the hibernate is trying to create this tables on the external db, i want the application data to be managed by hibernate and update when entity changes but for external DB i just want the app to connect to it so i can run some crud operation.

Need guidance as i am new to spring boot so not sure how to handle this scenario.

Comment: You will need to configure each datasource with name. There are many ways - 

1.  both as custom datasources - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access.configure-custom-datasource

2. Springboot config see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-multiple-datasources

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your primary repo by manual config like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  basePackageClasses = Todo.class,
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "todosEntityManagerFactory",
  transactionManagerRef = "todosTransactionManager"
)
public class TodoJpaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean todosEntityManagerFactory(
      @Qualifier("todosDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
      EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
          .dataSource(dataSource)
          .packages(Todo.class)
          .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager todosTransactionManager(
      @Qualifier("todosEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean todosEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(todosEntityManagerFactory.getObject()));
    }
}
```

Also need to add `@Primary` to your main datasource

```
@Configuration
public class TodoDatasourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.todos")
    public DataSourceProperties todosDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.todos.hikari")
    public DataSource todosDataSource() {
        return todosDataSourceProperties()
          .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
          .build();
    }
}
```

You can follow this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-multiple-datasources) and check this [example](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/persistence-modules/spring-data-jdbc/src/main/java/com/baeldung/springmultipledatasources)